# Pandas Dataframe - multiple values inside one cell?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on an assignment and I'm having trouble with Pandas (finding it very different to the MATLAB I'm used to).
I have a dataframe called 'main_DF' which has multiple columns (or series), one of these columns is called 'text-message'. I would like to take the text-message of each row, tokenize it into individual words and then place the list of those individual words into another column called 'text-message-tokens'.
This is what I have at the moment:

```
main_DF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['text-message', 'Label']) # creating empty dataframe

# filling with data
main_DF = main_DF.append({'text-message': "I am happy", 'Label':"happy"}, ignore_index=True)
main_DF = main_DF.append({'text-message': "I am sad", 'Label':"sad"}, ignore_index=True)

# print
print(main_DF)

# Tokenizing text-message
tokenize = CountVectorizer().build_tokenizer()

# Add tokenized message to main_DF
main_DF['text-message-tokens'] = tokenize(main_DF['text-message'][0]) # tokenize first row
main_DF['text-message-tokens'] = tokenize(main_DF['text-message'][1]) # tokenize second row

# print
print(main_DF)
```

This results in the following

[image]

I would like it to be like this in the end,
[image]

Comment: You can do this str(tokenize(main_DF['text-message'][1]))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) to apply tokenize on each text message:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

main_DF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['text-message', 'Label']) # creating empty dataframe

# filling with data
main_DF = main_DF.append({'text-message': "I am happy", 'Label':"happy"}, ignore_index=True)
main_DF = main_DF.append({'text-message': "I am sad", 'Label':"sad"}, ignore_index=True)

# print
print(main_DF)

# Tokenizing text-message
tokenize = CountVectorizer().build_tokenizer()

# Add tokenized message to main_DF
main_DF["text-message-tokens"] = main_DF["text-message"].apply(tokenize)

# print
print(main_DF)
```

Output

```
main_DF                                                                   
  text-message  Label text-message-tokens
0   I am happy  happy         [am, happy]
1     I am sad    sad           [am, sad]
```

Comment: Woah! Did not know that was possible. Thank you!! So there isn't even a need for a for loop if I had lots of data?

Comment: Indeed. In general, for processing large amounts of data, you don't want to be write explicit loops in the higher-level language (matlab and python) and instead let the library delegate the looping to a faster lower level language.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed something, with that code, some of my tokenized words have upper case starting letters?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the workings of the tokenizer. You could input your own function into `apply` that takes the cell as an argument and process it manually yourself if you don't like the count vectorizer behavior. For example, `main_DF["text-message"].apply(lambda cell: cell.lower().split(" "))`.